# Traefik without domain name

Tags: docker, traefik

Feww!!

I am new to Traefik and the documentions aren't helping in trying out a very basic test.

I am trying to run traefik basic example given on their home page [link](https://github.com/containous/traefik/tree/master/examples/quickstart/))  on a remote server, whom I access with an IP address and don't have a domain name as such. But all the doumentations and tutorial examples just looks to me the same - no discussion around what if a person don't have a domain name. (Neither can create as such as the server is behind a VPN.)

Question:-

How should I be configuring the traefik.frontend.rule when I don't have a domain name. If my IP address is say xx.xx.xxx.xxx.

compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ${traefikConfigDirectory}:/etc/traefik
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    # network_mode: host
  whoami:
    image: emilevauge/whoami
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/testpath
    # network_mode: host
```

config.toml

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
exposedByDefault = false
usebindportip=false
```

> [Update]

However, as suggested by @marvin, I adding traefik.port=80 label to whoami and also I had put `network_mode: host`, I was able to run. But how to make it run without putting network_mode to host?

Comment: Have you tried to use the IP in stead of a domain name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a host name.
The ip adress will point to your traefik : let's say 1.2.3.4:80 (you don't need the 80 indeed : it's just for the example)
For example, with some tomcat app (on 8080), the rule may be like  this :

```
- "traefik.docker.network: traefik"
- "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip: /somepath"
- "traefik.port=8080"
- ...
```

See : no ip in the rules. Because the rule is only matching the path after the ip or domain.

Here, every call to *1.2.3.4/somepath* will redirect to *1.2.3.4:8080*. You don't have to publish the 8080 port on the tomcat container.
If your application already have a path, just remove the "Strip" part : *"PathPrefix: /somepath"*

EDIT : with your compose

your compose would become stg like that (not tested):

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:alpine
    ...
    volumes:
      - ${traefikConfigDirectory}:/etc/traefik
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks: 
      - traefik-net
  whoami:
    image: emilevauge/whoami
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/testpath
      - traefil.docker.network=traefik-net
    networks: 
      - traefik-net

networks:
    traefik-net: {}
```

Comment: I am not able fully follow through the answer. This the compose yaml file - https://codeshare.io/5zY8bW. and this is how the toml looks like https://codeshare.io/5wYe0R. But when i check the browser, it says site cannot be reached. Looks like, using IP address it is not even able to reach traefik. I think i am missed something that is to do with network. But when I use network-mode as host, i see a 404 error instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, my proxy prevents me from reaching your shared codes. Did you enable traefik dasboard and can you reach it? https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/api/

Comment: But I just observed that adding labels for docker.network and port as you mentioned, I was able to get it working. Also i had to add network_mode=host as well.
 But I still have to figure out the logic why it wasn't working and if it is required why it was not there in the documentation example.

Comment: Yes network is requested, but you don't need to switch to "host" mode : just create a network (eg. "traefik"), add it to both services (traefik and whoami), and use the matching traefik label to state that this must be the network it will use to connect to the containers  . There are some good example on this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-traefik-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-docker-containers-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: "and use the matching traefik label to state that this must be the network it will use to connect to the containers" Unable to understand this statement. Can you please let me know what is meant by 'using the matching traefik lable" ?

Comment: Right now only problem that I see it when both the traefik and whoami are on the host network by using network_mode=host, it works, but if i add a network using traefik.docker.network label to both of them it stops working. What I am missing...

Comment: Don't use host mode. See at the exemple I provided in the answer above

Comment: I went through the digitalocean link you provided still could not figure out the problem. Indeed sometime in last 3 days I might have visited this and several other links but they all are same, same sort of information.

Comment: Did you try the example I added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187870/discussion-between-marvin-and-vishal-daga).

Comment: There was a mistake on my part and few other things working together to confuse me. 1) Basically it was working with network_mode=host as there was another traefik container running leading to confusion. (2)I put wrong port in the toml file, and was wondering why it was working with network_mode=host and not otherwise.  All of these made me think things aren't working as per documentation and nobody is discussing on the issue I am facing. Thanks for the help and offering to chat!